# accordion overlay from next item

Tags: wordpress, accordion

I'm building a site with takeaway food. I'm using an accordion to display different categories. In the accordion i display a product category from woocommerce. If I open the first accordion-item, then there's an overlay from the second accordion. I'm unable to find the solution. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance. Link to view the problem: http://www.testteunie.be/italian-delights/

Comment: There is a `ReferenceError: scroll_amount_for_sticky is not defined
 ` error in your console. May be this can be an issue

Comment: Please do not provide links in lieu of code.  Future readers do not benefit once the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css and try

```
.wpb_wrapper .accordion_content.ui-accordion-content-active{
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```